# Why JWT contains EXP claim even if I set Expires to null?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt

I need the immortal JWT token. Of course I could set some big value to Expires, but I prefer do not have exp claim in my token at all. Standard .net core CreateEncodedJwt allows to pass null in expires, notBefore, issuedAt. I pass null for all of them, and my token contains exp token (+1 hour). What is going on?!

```cs
var securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("FF804E8A-2A0E-4F94-A6F5-8325822F8DF5"));

var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim("type1", "value1"),
    new Claim("type2", "value2")

};

var token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().CreateEncodedJwt(
    issuer: null,
    audience: null,
    subject: new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
    notBefore: null,
    issuedAt: null,
    expires: null,
    signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(securityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));
```

This is tool for parsing: https://jwt.io

This is my token:

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0eXBlMSI6InZhbHVlMSIsInR5cGUyIjoidmFsdWUyIiwibmJmIjoxNTY1NDI5MzY2LCJleHAiOjE1NjU0MzI5NjYsImlhdCI6MTU2NTQyOTM2Nn0.UvJiOQNO_yMzdenf5jAotPHj7zrcEUApraezzcVSicA

This is how it looks inside:

> {
>     "type1": "value1",
>     "type2": "value2",
>     "nbf": 1565429366,
>     "exp": 1565432966,
>     "iat": 1565429366
>   }

Please help to get rid nbf, exp, iat. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think you should/can. Jwt is a security process where you issue a token at some time (iat) and it expires at some time (exp). When passing the null value to the expiration time, I think you are letting the code choosing the default expiration time. What are you trying to achieve with jwt without expiration ?

Comment: That's is the temporary solution for fast development. As I can see, JWT tokens from PHP-backend doesn't contain exp, that's the point.

Comment: I don't think it's the way it has been handled and should be. As I stated, Jwt is a security process where iat and exp are being one of the important parts of the security. Why is the purposed of such a process ? Transferring data from back to front ? You don't need a flawed jwt token for that

Comment: If data are sensitive, please implemented the security as it should be instead of "fast development" with holes in your security. Ethics...

Comment: Ok, but why that method has nullable-DateTime as type of parameter? If expiration date is required, they could use DateTime (not null).

Comment: Because it can be impossible to retrieve the value for some reason (written in the doc here :https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/dn464119%28v%3dvs.114%29). I did not found anything about jwt without exp and iat. You still did not provide any utility to this request.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Simplified version of `JwtSecurityTokenHandle` code that creates a token contains the next piece:

```
if (SetDefaultTimesOnTokenCreation && 
    (!expires.HasValue || !issuedAt.HasValue || !notBefore.HasValue))
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    if (!expires.HasValue)
        expires = now + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(TokenLifetimeInMinutes);

    if (!issuedAt.HasValue)
        issuedAt = now;

    if (!notBefore.HasValue)
        notBefore = now;
}
```

So you basically had to set `SetDefaultTimesOnTokenCreation` to false. And the standard for [JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519#page-9) says nothing against empty `exp` claim:

> The "exp" (expiration time) claim identifies the expiration time on
> or after which the JWT MUST NOT be accepted for processing.

> Its value MUST be a number
> containing a NumericDate value.  Use of this claim is OPTIONAL.

So all correct implementations of JWT format validators should successfully validate token without that claim inside.

Comment: +1 for looking at the source code. Generally, a good practice if you want to know how something works instead of guessing it.